# Sending emails with JAVAMAIL without authenticating every time

Tags: java, spring, email, model-view-controller, jakarta-mail

Hello I'm working on an admin dashboard with spring MVC, and it's the first time I use javamail.

My question is: Is there any way I can authenticate to the session at first and then use this instance to send more emails without authentication? (while the session is still available).

With the method I'm using I need to save the sender's email and password as "clear text" to authenticate every time.

So anyone please have any suggestions on how to manage session and how to store email and password to authenticate when I need to send/receive emails?

Thank you!

So here is the code I'm using to send the email:

```
@Override
public boolean sendEmail(EmailTMP e) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    final String password=e.getSender().getInboxPassword();
    final String from = e.getSender().getInboxEmail();
    String name=e.getSender().getNom();
    String toAddress = e.getReceiver();
    String subject=e.getSubject();
    String textContent=e.getContent();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

   <!-- I need to replace the code below to automatically authenticate and get the current session-->
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
                }
              });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse(toAddress));
        message.setSubject(subject);


        message.setText(textContent);
        InternetAddress fromAddress=new InternetAddress(from, name);
        message.setFrom(fromAddress);
        Transport.send(message);

        return true;

    } catch (MessagingException c) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a `Transport` object from the session and keep using it, calling `Transport.sendMessage()` with that instance, instead of using the static `Transport.send()` method. Call `Transport.close()` when you're finished with it.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer! Can you please explain more and maybe give me a simple exemple? And maybe you suggestion force the user to send to same email everytime by only using the same Transport.send?

Comment: @skmd Of course it doesn't force the user to send the same email every time. You can send as many different emails as you like. What a strange suggestion.

Comment: can you please post an exemple?

Comment: Err, `Transport transport = session.getTransport()`? *Etcetera?* How hard is it really?

Comment: Reusing the same Transport object to send multiple messages will work for as long as the server allows you to keep the connection open, which is usually not very long.  If, for example, you need to be able to send multiple messages over a period of hours or days, you'll need to keep the clear text username and password around somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Spring framework, you can achieve this using [JavaMailSenderImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html) provided by spring. 
You can configure it as a bean in you spring context xml file in following way:

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${email.server.host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${email.server.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${email.sender.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${email.sender.password}"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${email.sender.prop.mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">${email.sender.prop.mail.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">${email.sender.prop.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

Then you have to get this bean in your application to send email eg.

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
```

And in following way you will use it to send email.

```
SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
message.setTo(to);
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(textMessage);
mailSender.send(message);
```

So in this way you don't have to initialize email sender each time and also need not worry about session management.

Comment: But does it accompish single authentication? Which is what the question is about.

Comment: Yes as that bean is by default singleton, authentication will be only done once while loading spring context. So single authentication will be achieved.